# Toggle/document/click and close other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the scenario.

**Step 1-** Click action opens a drop down that can be closed on click of anywhere except the dropdown area and action text.

**Problem 1-** I want this also to get close on click of action text only. So the solution will be it get close on click of area anywhere except dropdown area and also on click of action text.
[image]

**Step 2 -**
On click of multiple action text opens multiple dropdowns .

**Problem 2-** I want it the way that if one gets open other gets close.
[image]

**Code:**

```js
$('.ToggleClass a').click(function(ev) {
  $(this).next('.ActionDropDown').fadeIn(500);


});
$(document).click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var container = $(".ToggleClass");

  //check if the clicked area is dropDown or not
  if (container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    $('.ActionDropDown').fadeOut(500);
  }

});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: arial;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #cbeeff
}

.row1 {
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.row1-2 {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-right: 2px solid #000
}

.row1-2+.row1-2 {
  border-right: 0px;
}

.row1-2 a {
  color: #ff4886;
  float: none;
}

.ActionDropDown {
  position: absolute;
  background: #7bd4ff;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  top: 20px;
  padding: 30px 10px;
  display: none;
  z-index: 9;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  max-width: 180px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
.InfoDiv{ width:100%; padding:10px; background:#ffadc9;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-----Row 1--------->
<div class="row1">
  <div class="row1-2">Simple Text</div>
  <div class="row1-2 ToggleClass"> <a href="#">Action</a>
    <div class="ActionDropDown">
      I am a Drop Down !
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-----Row 1--------->
<!-----Row 2--------->
<div class="row1">
  <div class="row1-2">Simple Text</div>
  <div class="row1-2 ToggleClass"> <a href="#">Action</a>
    <div class="ActionDropDown">
      I am a Drop Down !
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-----Row 2--------->
<!-----Row 3--------->
<div class="row1">
  <div class="row1-2">Simple Text</div>
  <div class="row1-2 ToggleClass"> <a href="#">Action</a>
    <div class="ActionDropDown">
      I am a Drop Down !
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-----Row 3--------->

<div class="InfoDiv">
 <b>Info:</b> Right now click on Action on each row open drop down multiple times. What I want is when one drop down is open on click of action , the other drop down if open should get close.
</div>
```

Comment: Can't you run a fadeout on all ActionDropDown objects before fading in the one you clicked? E.g. insert ´$('.ActionDropDown').fadeOut(500);´ on the second line of JS?

Comment: Thanks for the suggeston but it solves only problem 2 not problem 1.. problem 1 is it should also close current dropdown on click of action text.

Comment: @Niklas can you solve problem 1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see snippet below or [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/k33hu40f/3/)

added this line to your jQuery :

`$(this).parents(".row").siblings(".row").find(".ActionDropDown").fadeOut(500)`

also added a common class to all parent rows ( class `row` ) in your HTML

you need to search the other ActionDropDown and close it the same time you open another one

EDIT : added new JQ code for click outside the container + explanation

you can add a new condition to the IF

`&& $(".ActionDropDown").has(e.target).length === 0)` -> if the clicked element is not a descendant of `ActionDropDown` . only if you need it

see updated fiddle or snippet below

EDIT2 : added condition to check if dropdown is open when click on the same Action .

```
var dropDown = $(this).next('.ActionDropDown')
if ($(dropDown).is(":visible")) {
  $(dropDown).fadeOut(500)
} else {
 $(dropDown).fadeIn(500)
}
```

see snippet below or the updated fiddle

```js
$('.ToggleClass a').click(function(ev) {
var dropDown = $(this).next('.ActionDropDown')
  if ($(dropDown).is(":visible")) {
   $(dropDown).fadeOut(500)
 } else {
  $(dropDown).fadeIn(500)
 }

 $(this).parents(".row").siblings(".row").find(".ActionDropDown:visible").fadeOut(500)


});
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{

    if (!$(".ActionDropDown").is(e.target) ) // if the target of the click is not the dropDown
   {
        $(".ActionDropDown").fadeOut(500);
    }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: arial;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #cbeeff
}

.row1 {
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.row1-2 {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-right: 2px solid #000
}

.row1-2+.row1-2 {
  border-right: 0px;
}

.row1-2 a {
  color: #ff4886;
  float: none;
}

.ActionDropDown {
  position: absolute;
  background: #7bd4ff;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  top: 20px;
  padding: 30px 10px;
  display: none;
  z-index: 9;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  max-width: 180px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
.InfoDiv{ width:100%; padding:10px; background:#ffadc9;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-----Row 1--------->
<div class="row row1">
  <div class="row1-2">Simple Text</div>
  <div class="row1-2 ToggleClass"> <a href="#">Action</a>
    <div class="ActionDropDown">
      I am a Drop Down !
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-----Row 1--------->
<!-----Row 2--------->
<div class="row row1">
  <div class="row1-2">Simple Text</div>
  <div class="row1-2 ToggleClass"> <a href="#">Action</a>
    <div class="ActionDropDown">
      I am a Drop Down !
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-----Row 2--------->
<!-----Row 3--------->
<div class="row row1">
  <div class="row1-2">Simple Text</div>
  <div class="row1-2 ToggleClass"> <a href="#">Action</a>
    <div class="ActionDropDown">
      I am a Drop Down !
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-----Row 3--------->

<div class="InfoDiv">
 <b>Info:</b> Right now click on Action on each row open drop down multiple times. What I want is when one drop down is open on click of action , the other drop down if open should get close.
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but your solution doesnot solve problem 1.. problem 1 is it should also close current dropdown on click of action text.

Comment: Its not working properly its fading in again on click of Action text. Please check again @Mihai

Comment: please explain more. my solution is like this 1. fading IN when click on ACTION + faiding OUT any other visible dropdowns. 2 .  fading OUT when click anywhere on the document except the dropdown. isn't this how you wanted it ?

Comment: yes thats what i want + 1 more thing.. Also fade out dropdown on click of action text..

Comment: In your case when i click on action text of the current drop down (opened ) again.. its fades in the drop down again.. Check it you will see it too

Comment: @SahilDhir is this what you were looking for ?